# Laravel posting button from controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to populate my databse using ajax+laravel. but when I am trying to post my delete button I get some errors.
2 to be exact 
1) I cant find a way to make it call destroy function from inside the controller 
2) The Javascript I have inside my blade does not execute (works when the button is created inside the blade) that my problematic button

```
<form method="post" class="delete_form" action=" $this->callAction(\\'destroy\\', [\\'id\\' => $row[\\'id\\']]); ">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

and I am trying to execute this from inside the same controller (this part works I I crate a button in my blade (did it for testing))

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $userList = users::find($id);
    $userList->delete();
    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('successs', 'Data Deleted');
}
```

Comment: "_that my problematic button_" That's not a `<button>`, but a `<form>`. That action should point to a route, not call a Controller method.

Comment: Hi, I Updated the code just to be more clear.  I think I tried what you are suggesting {{ route('users.destroy', ['id' => $row['id']]) }}"  but it was not executing at all. it was like I was clicking an empty button

          <form method="post" class="delete_form" action=" {{ route('users.destroy', ['id' => $row['id']]) }} ">

Exactly what I tried

Comment: Your action after your edit probably won't work because it is not parsed via Blade. (You could try `{{ route('users.destroy') }}` for your `action`). `$id` should be a input/hidden field in your form, not in your form's action. You also need to add `@csrf` in your form.

Answer (score 0):

use `{{route('/users/destroy', ['id' => $row['id'}])}}`

in the `form` `action`

Comment: Show me your route file @Demeteor

Comment: Route::resource('users','UserController');
Route::get('/users/index', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/users/index/users', 'UserController@action')->name('index.action');
Route::get('/users/destroy', 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy');


thats all I have in the route.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21102571)

Comment: Hi this still did not work, I tried doing some ajax here and there, adding new methods but still nothing get deleted.